# main tag in html / CSS

Tags: program-entry-point

I do have problems understand the tag `</main>`.

The project im looking at only has one `</main>` closing tag at the end, it has no opening tag of `<main>` which confuses me in the first place. It also has `main {}`  in CSS. In order to try to understand what it does, I have played around with it a little.

As I comment out the `</main>` in html, absolutely nothing changes, which I understand if it has only informativ character, but the part where I get confused is, what is the `main {....}` in the CSS referring to, since when I comment this out, it will mess up the styling of the hole page.

edit: Since it seems to be unclear what my problem is: The problem is, that `main {.....}` in CSS does (!) influence the styling of the site, even without an opening `<main>` tag in html, and even without ANY `<main>` tag in html (for example if I remove the `</main>` tag in html.

How can a `main {....}` in CSS have influence on the styling, if there isn t even any `<main>` tag in the html whatsoever?

Answer (score 1):

main{...} in css reffers to the styling of the main tag.

More about the element css selector
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element.asp

You can learn more about the main tag here
https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_main.asp

And more about css selectors here

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Also note that the main tag must have opening amd closing tag

Comment: If ithis solved your problem, can you sign my answer as answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

You have to either add a  tag, or remove main{...}.

Comment: but why does the main{...} influence the styling of the page, if there is no opening tag for </main> in html, and why does main{....} even style the page if i remove the </main> tag in html completely. But as soon as i remove the main{....} in CSS, the styling of the hole page is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

The  tag specifies the main content of a document.

The content inside the  element should be unique to the document. It should not contain any content that is repeated across documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms.

Note: There must not be more than one  element in a document. The  element must NOT be a descendant of an , , , , or  element.

Answer (score 0):

just refers to the main content of the page, it does nothing. Main{...} is styling in the CSS page.